# multi inherit or access the property and method outside the object

Tags: javascript

```
var ob = function(){

};
ob.prototype.func = function(){

};

var t = function(){
    this.p=0;
    this.function1(){

    }
    var a=new ob();
    a.func=function(){//overrides the func

         //hope to access this.p this.function1

    }

};
```

is it possible to make a can access this.p this.function1  ？

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to `this` from inside `t` if you want to access it within `a.func`. Try the following:

```
var t = function(){
    var this_t = this; // Use this_t to access this.p and this.function1 inside a

    this.p=0;
    this.function1 = function(){

    }

    var a=new ob();
    a.func = function(){//overrides the func

        this_t.p = 1;
        this_t.function1();

    }

};
```